# Connection Between Sum of Divisors of $p^n$ (p a prime) and number of 1-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_p^{n+1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime, $n$ a non-negative integer. On one hand, the sum of the divisors of $p^n$ (denoted by $\sigma_1(p^n)$) is given by
$\sigma_1(p^n)=1+ \dots +p^n=\cfrac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$.

The number of 1 dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_p^{n+1}$ is computed by the number of nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{F}_p^{n+1}$, divided by the number of bases for a 1 dimensional subspace (this procedure can of course be generalized for the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_p^{m}$), which yields the same formula given above, namely 
$\cfrac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$.

My question is regarding these formulas.
Why are they the same? Is it pure coincidence, or is there some connection I am not seeing?

Comment: I'd say this is kind of an incidence. Note that this kind of expressions shows up at various places: $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$ is called the $q$-analog of the number $n$